# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' client side fix

Tags: javascript, api, cors

I am trying to get free NFL data from an [API by suredbits](http://suredbits.com/api/). Unfortunately, in their header, they have not added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, which creates a CORS issue. When I try and run code like this...

```
$.getJSON("http://api.suredbits.com/nfl/v0/stats/jones/julio", function(playerData) {
      alert(playerdata); 
}
```

I keep getting this error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

So basically, is their any way to fix their mistake through the client side?

Comment: no, because CORS protects resources - you could proxy requests via **your** server, then CORS isn't an issue

Comment: That's what I've come to realize after reading just about every question about this on stackoverflow. Are there any tutorials or anything that could teach me how to do that?

Comment: depends on your server side technology

Comment: You can just make the calls serverside. I don't think this is so much a mistake by them, they simply don't want to be called by any random browser internet-wide.

Comment: pvg, what do you mean make calls serverside? I don't manage the api if thats what you mean.

Comment: I have to admit it is a bit strange the API wouldn't include that header. I believe the best thing to do for now is to reach out to SuredBits (https://twitter.com/suredbits) and ask if that's a mistake or if they have any alternative methods of querying the data from JS (with a token?). The only other alternative to getting this work from JS is setting up a proxy on your web server - all this means is that it is your own server getting data from the API and then returning it to your script (thus avoiding the CORS issues).

Comment: Matt, are there any good tutorials to achieving that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is actually a way to fix it from client side: by changing the request URL to `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.suredbits.com/nfl/v0/stats/jones/julio`:

```js
const proxyURL = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const requestURL = "http://api.suredbits.com/nfl/v0/stats/jones/julio";
$.getJSON(proxyURL + requestURL, function(playerData) {
  console.log(playerData);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Yeah, that’s not *exactly* fixing it from the client side—since what it’s actually doing is, causing the request to get made through https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/, which is an open CORS proxy that just adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header so that browsers will allow your frontend JavaScript code to access the response.

But as demonstrated in the code snippet in the answer, it definitely doesn’t require any changes to the server hosting the API endpoint you want to get data from. Instead all it requires a trivial change to your own frontend code.

Of course relying on a public open proxy like this is not the right solution in all cases. But at least it’s a good solution in the case where the API provider just hasn’t gotten around to CORS-enabling their API so that you could send requests to it directly and get responses you can use.

The *How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems* section of the answer at *[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141)* has a few more details.

Comment: It's not 'not exactly fixing it from the client-side', it's not a client-side fix at all.